# Consulta de tabela associativa no Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Bom... Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação no Django de consumo de energia residencial...
Eu tenho três tabelas: Ambiente, Aparelho e uma associativa, Aparelho_Ambiente onde tenho chaves estrangeiras para as duas tabelas. O meu problema e o seguinte, eu quero fazer uma consulta onde traga os aparelhos que estão cadastrados em um ambiente ex: Sala = [televisão, Lâmpada, modem, ar-condicionado...], Quarto = [abajur, ventilador, ar-condicionado...]. Consegui fazer uma consulta onde mostra os aparelhos que tem no ambiente, só que na hora de renderizar o template, o que é mostrado um dicionario ex:{aparelho__nome : 'lampada'} e, não só o nome do aparelho em si. Sou novato em django e gostaria saber de como realizar essa consulta com orm do django? Desde já, muito obrigado!

```
class Ambiente(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nome do ambiente', max_length=100, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Atalho', blank=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Criado em',auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Atualizado em', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Aparelho(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nome do aparelho', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Atalho', blank=True, max_length=100, unique=True)
    potencia = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Potencia em watts', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Criado em', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Atualizado em', auto_now=True)

    objects = AparelhoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Aparelho_Ambiente(models.Model):
    
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'minutos/dia'),
        (2, 'horas/dia'),
    )
    
    ambiente = models.ForeignKey(Ambiente, verbose_name='Ambiente', related_name='ambientes', on_delete=models.deletion.DO_NOTHING)
    aparelho = models.ForeignKey(Aparelho, verbose_name='Aparelho', related_name='aparelhos', on_delete=models.deletion.DO_NOTHING)
    quantidade = models.IntegerField('Quantidade', default=0, blank=True,)
    tempo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Tempo de uso', null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=2, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Criado em', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Atualizado em', auto_now=True)
```

View

```
def simulator(request, slug):
    context={}
    ambientes = Ambiente.objects.prefetch_related('ambientes').order_by('id')
    apps = Aparelho_Ambiente.objects.prefetch_related('ambientes','aparelhos').values(
        'aparelho__name'
    ).filter(ambiente__slug=slug)
    context = {

        'ambientes':ambientes,
        'apps':apps,
    }
    return render(request, 'aparelhos/simulador.html', context)
```

Template

```
{% for ambiente in ambientes %}
        <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('{{ ambiente.name }}', this, 'red')"><a>{{ ambiente.name }}</a></button>
    
        <div id="{{ ambiente.name }}" class="tabcontent">
            {% for app in apps %}
                {{ app }}
            {% empty %}
                <p>Nenhum aparelho encontrado</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Olá viva, partilha o que já tentaste.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer uma consulta onde trago os aparelhos que tem em um ambiente, só que na hora de passar pro template, os dados estão mostrando como dicionario: {'aparelho__name':'ventilador'...}

Comment: ```                                                                                                                        def simulator(request, slug):
    context={}
    ambientes = Ambiente.objects.prefetch_related('ambientes').order_by('id')
    apps = Aparelho_Ambiente.objects.prefetch_related('ambientes','aparelhos').values(
        'aparelho__name'
    ).filter(ambiente__slug=slug)
    context = {

        'ambientes':ambientes,
        'apps':apps,
    }
    return render(request, 'aparelhos/simulador.html', context)                                     ```

Comment: Edita a tua questão e coloca esse código mais o do template sendo muito grande, coloca só a parte onde tens essas variáveis para simplificar.

Comment: Já está editado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tua solução está muito próxima da que funciona, uma vez que indicas que já retorna o esperado, só precisas de mudar uma linha no teu html.

```
    {% for ambiente in ambientes %}
        <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('{{ ambiente.name }}', this, 'red')"><a>{{ ambiente.name }}</a></button>
        <div id="{{ ambiente.name }}" class="tabcontent">
            {% for app in apps %}
                {{ app.aparelho__name }} <!-- <==== AQUI adicionas o que definiste no values 'aparelho__name' na tua consulta com o ORM de Django-->
            {% empty %}
                <p>Nenhum aparelho encontrado</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Obrigado! mas acabei alterando a estrutura dos modelos... Removi a tabela associativa, e adicionei um ManyToManyField no model Ambiente relacionando com model Aparelho. Fui um pouco impaciente, mas agradeço muito a sua atenção. Em algum momento irei refazer pra testar a sua solução. Obrigado, novamente!